# Change date language - Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have done this before, but I have forgotten it. I have searched online alot for solving this problem, but haven't found exactly what I am looking for.

I need to change the language of the date on Wordpress. I just updated to the new WP, so I guess the new version has overwritten my old PHP file with dates.

How do I solve this? I believe my language, Norwegian, needs to be translated manually.

Comment: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/change-the-language-of-the-date-038-time and http://codex.wordpress.org/Translating_WordPress#Date_and_Time_Locale_Settings may help you..

Answer (score 0):

WordPress has date_i18n to retrieve the date in localized format, based on timestamp.

Try:

```
echo date_i18n("d F Y (H:i)",$date) ;
```

Comment: Thanks. But I got an error when I replaced the old time-thing. 

"Notice: Undefined variable: date in (address of the file) on line 84 01 January 1970 (00:00)"